# Incorrect amount of posts returned when filtering related Woo products by custom taxonomy

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm currently filtering related Woocommerce products by a custom taxonomy, which I've achieved using my code below, however the amount of products that it retrieves is behaving very odd.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', 'rare_related_products_by_custom_taxonomy');
function rare_related_products_by_custom_taxonomy( $args ) {

    global $post;

    $tags = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, "custom_taxonomy" );
    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
            $tags_array[] .= $tag->term_id;
    }

  unset( $args['post__in'] );
  $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy',
                'field'    => 'id',
                'terms'    => $tags_array,
            ),
        );
  return $args;

}
```

For some reason, regardless of what I set posts_per_page to, it returns an incorrect amount. Trying different terms, I can't determine any pattern to it.

For example I have posts_per_page set to 40 (just for troubleshooting) I get the below results.

- Term 1: 25 returned products (out of 32 in-stock products
- Term 2: 10 returned products (out of 25 in-stock products)
- Term 3: 17 returned products (out of 55 in-stock products)

My best guess is that it has something to do with me no longer using the get_related function which, among other things,  "ensures we always have enough results, it will check $limit before returning the cached result, if not recalc".

However I haven't being able to work out how implement a custom taxonomy into this function, hence why I'm currently bypassing it.

So my question is either:

- How can I return the correct amount of related products using my code above?
- Or if need be, how can alter the get_related function to use custom taxonomies?